# Using AWS-SDK for DynamoDB, createSet creates a Map instead of a Set

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

If you were to create a new item and leave an empty list (i.e `{ a: 'string', b: [] }` in your params, it'll convert this to a List Attribute. What I actually want is a String Set Attribute, or SS.

I scoured through the documentation more and found [createSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) and was hopeful this will solve my problem. But unfortunately it created a Map Attribute instead. Currently, this is how I'm creating it:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

(async () => {
    const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    const params = {
        TableName: 'some_table_in_dynamodb',
        Item: {
            a: 'some string',
            b: docClient.createSet([])
        }
    };

    const response = await docClient.put(params).promise();
    console.log(response);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution from playing with the UI on DynamoDB: The list CANNOT be empty, otherwise it'll convert it to a Map attribute. to fix this, just add an empty string.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

(async () => {
    const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    const params = {
        TableName: 'some_table_in_dynamodb',
        Item: {
            a: 'some string',
            b: docClient.createSet(['']) // ADD STRING FOR SS ATTRIBUTE
        }
    };

    const response = await docClient.put(params).promise();
    console.log(response);
})();
```